# Export all saved wifi passwords from win 8 to external storage (usb)

Tags: windows, command-line, passwords, export

Is there a command which I can use in command prompt to save all wifi passwords (on al interfaces) to an external usb?
win 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a bulk password export App that I have seen.

However you can export the password from a Wireless Profile (Windows 8 and 10 at least).

Open an Admin Command Prompt. Type the following:

netsh wlan show profile name="Profile Name"   key=clear to see password

You can make a batch file of this to export the password to another file.

Comment: this is what i wanted to confirm, i use netsh on win 10 all the time, but will it work on win8?

Comment: Yes. I used netsh when I had Windows 8 .